# IE 11 Crashes When Popping Out Tab and Crossrider Extension is Enabled

Tags: crossrider

I recently started using Crossrider to make a basic IE extension that changes a specific website's layout to make it a bit more usable. I'm testing with the staging build and it successfully installs. However, I have encountered the following two problems:

1) In IE 11, I have multiple tabs that open simultaneously when I launch the browser (because I have multiple default home pages). When I try to pop one of the tabs out into its own window, that tab crashes for several seconds until I finally have to click the "Recover Webpage" button. It occurs for any page and repros in IE 11 on Windows 10 and Windows 8.1.

2) The "Open in OneNote" links from OneNote Online no longer work. The button appears, but it does not function. Additionally, the link to install the staging extension directly from crossrider no longer appears automatically as it normally would. I have to disable the extension and reload IE in order to install the extension from the crossrider developer portal.

Comment: I recreated the mentioned scenarios and tested using a Crossrider extension. In both instances I could not reproduce the issue. It may help if you provide the extension id and a video showing the issue. If you are unable to post a video to this thread, you can open a ticket with Crossrider Support by emailing support@crossrider.com [**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: Thanks for the response, Shlomo. Here is the affected extension:
http://crossrider.com/apps/75682/ide
I'll post a video if there's no evident reason for the crash that exists in my code. Thanks for looking.

Comment: From a brief look at your code I can see an syntax error (a semi-colon after the closing brace) on line 2 of _extension.js_. IE is very particular about syntax and the semi-colon may be causing the crash (technically the closure isn't required either). Try removing the semi-colon and optionally the braces (`if (!appAPI.isMatchPages("*XXXXXXX*")) return;`) and see it it resolves the issue.

Comment: It still has the same issues. Please check the extension to see if I followed your instructions correctly and let me know if there are any other suggestions.

Comment: I tested your extension on some simply multiple homepage sites (google.com, yahoo.com) and could not reproduce the issues. Can you provide the homepages you are using and I'll test?

Comment: The crashing issue was (and is) a less impactful problem. Also, I was able to determine that it only repros when I set one of the homepages as a specific intranet website --- so there's a viable workaround, although it's a bit weird.

The main problem now is that users can not press "Open in OneNote" or "Open in Word" when they're using an Office 365 document in the web browser. This can be consistently reproduced. Load the extension, create a new Word doc from any O365 account, and try it out.

Comment: This also breaks Lync/Skype for Business conference links. (For these types of links, you put a URL in the web browser and the Lync client should open up and be directed to the correct conference call. However, it just hangs on the Lync page and doesn't load the Lync client) So... The problem seems to be that, for Crossrider plugins, browser links to Office applications are broken.

Comment: Thank you for identifying the issue. As you may be aware, Chrome and Firefox extensions run in a sandbox environment which unfortunately is not provided by IE and can hence lead to conflicts on occasion. I managed to reproduce the issue and have added it to the dev team's issues queue to investigate, though it is unlikely to be fixed in the near future due to workload. If this feature is critical to your extension then perhaps another extension framework may meet your needs.

Comment: Shlomo - I really appreciate the promptness and honesty in yours answers. Thank you for your assistance. I'll keep exploring options and, after my experience with you, I truly hope that Crossrider becomes a viable extension framework for my scenario in the future.